# How to define class in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS :

```
#cssmenu {
  background: #333;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 12em;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Here is my html :

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='normal'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li class='bold'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to divide **a**s to two groups, normal and bold. I tried this :

```
#cssmenu a.normal {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu a.bold{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But this didn't work. How can I give classes correctly for this CSS file? Thanks.

Comment: use dot    .classname

Comment: Show us your html structure and sample to reproduce your issue

Comment: @GopsAB I added my html. Thanks.

Comment: At what situations you want bold font and normal font?

Comment: When class is bold, it should look bold, otherwise normal font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `bold` and `normal` class of `li` not `a`.

Change css like:

```
#cssmenu li.normal a{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu li.bold a{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5bybx1e/1/)**

Or

```
#cssmenu li.normal span{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu li.bold span{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Whereever you want `bold` add a class to  `#cssmenu a`

```
.bold{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Whereever you want `normal`, remove `bold class`

```css
#cssmenu li.normal span{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu li.bold span{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='normal'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li class='bold'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#cssmenu a{
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight : normal;
}

#cssmenu a.bold{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

html

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<a class="bold"/>
</div
```